# How with wsl 2 open new ubuntu terminal from command line?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

How can i open new ubuntu terminal windows or terminal subtab with terminal command?
I need to execute it from current opened ubuntu terminal

Answer (score 0):

You should have programs from your Windows `%PATH%` available in your WSL `$PATH`, so you may be able to just use `cmd.exe /c bash` or similar

Alternatively, you could install an X server on Windows (like Xming) and run a terminal emulator like konsole or Terminator inside WSL